# Emacs multi-term as a login shell

Tags: shell, emacs

How can I configure multi-term in Emacs to allow login shell? Ruby Version Manager uses it...

```
    You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
    Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
    Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use variable `multi-term-program-switches`:

```
(setq multi-term-program-switches "--login")
```

Here is the documentation:

multi-term-program-switches is a variable defined in `multi-term.el'.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
The command-line switches to pass to the term program.

You can customize this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in `multi-term`, but in `shell` this would be something along the lines:

<kbd>M-:</kbd>`(let ((explicit-bash-args (list "-login"))) (shell (get-buffer-create "*login-shell*")))`

Will create a buffer with login shell in it, to test it do:

```
shopt | grep login
```

Which should print

```
login_shell on
```

For Bash.

It is also odd for an interactive program to require a login shell. It is not impossible to run login shell interactively, however most commonly it is not run interactively.